# Invalid preceding regular expression given by Sieve

Tags: regex, sieve-language

I am attempting to write a filter that matches the regex `^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)?[a-zA-Z]+\.)?(example)\.com$`. (I want to capture every email that is from a specific domain). However, it keeps returning the error `Invalid preceding regular expression`. The expression works correctly so I am unsure why this error is occuring. This is the first time I've written a sieve filter so am I missing something?

Comment: Try `^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)?[a-zA-Z]+\.)?(example)\.com$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżewThat worked! Thank you. What was the issue with my original expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)?[a-zA-Z]+\.)?(example)\.com$
```

It appeas that the regex should comply with the POSIX ERE regex syntax that does not allow [non-capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions).

So the solution was to replace all `(?:` with `(` in this regex.